# how do you paste unique values without showing the rows that were skipped?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract the unique purchase orders from a row and paste that list into another sheet. The problem is that when I paste, it doesn't list the purchase orders sequentially (a1,a2,a3,a4); It pastes them from the location that they were copied (a3,a112,a194, etc)
here's the macro:

```
Sub unique_values()
'
' unique_values Macro
'
'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1:A394").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your sheets?

Comment: hate to ask, but how do i do that?

Comment: you can take a screen shot and add it as picture in your question

Comment: Use an Advanced Filter, it's designed to extract data and copy to another location.

Answer (score 1):

Just updated you code a little. You were almost there. Just delete the empty cells after you copy.

```
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1:A394").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
    On Error Resume Next
With Range("A:A")
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) > 0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
End With
```